# Enumerate available screens in Tauri / with Rust

Tags: rust, getusermedia, tauri

I'm considering migrating our existing electron application to Tauri.

We're not using any fancy features, except for one where I'm not sure if/how it can be achieved in Tauri (or with a plugin written in Rust): **We need to enumerate all available screens.** Today we are doing this with electron's `desktopCapturer.getSources(...)`.

Is there a similar feature in Tauri? Or does Rust support this, so we can write a Rust plugin for Tauri?

Note that the resulting screen objects must contain an id which is compatible with Chrome's `getUserMedia(...)`:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: false,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
      chromeMediaSourceId: SCREEN_ID_FROM_LIST_OF_ENUMERATED_SCREENS
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does [`tauri::Window::available_monitors`](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.5.3/tauri/window/struct.Window.html#method.available_monitors) help?

Comment: I've seen that api, but apparently it only returns a (human-readable) name, not an id I could pass to getUserMedia...

Comment: Your exact issue seems to have been discussed here[1] and here[2]. It seems to be doable, with some caveats. I don't have actual code so can't post this as an answer, but hope it fully solves your question.

[1] https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/5572

[2] https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/2600

Comment: @TachyonicBytes thanks for the links. I think I came across at least one of those in my research. Unfortunately they don't really show a way to enumerate the screens in a similar way like Electron's desktopCapturer.getSources(). Maybe we'll resort to using the default selection dialog that pops up when calling getDisplayMedia().